# Request method "GET" is not supported

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring, aplicación-web

Cuando abro el link localhost:8082/register me salta el error:

2023-01-19T10:38:07.913+01:00  WARN 8540 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported]

Codigo Controller:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String userRegistration(@ModelAttribute User user){
        System.out.println(user.toString());
        return "index";
    }

}
```

codigo html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="register" method="POST">
        <h1>Learning Spring boot whit HMTL form</h1>
        First Name <br/>
        <input type="text" name="fname"> <br/>

        last Name <br/>
        <input type="text" name="lname"> <br/>

        Email <br/>
        <input type="email" name="email"> <br/>

        Password <br/>
        <input type="password" name="password"> <br/>

        <input type="submit" name="Enviar"/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sin manejar Spring/Spring Boot: en el controller estás mostrando que tenés un `@PostMapping("/register")`. El error te dice _Request method 'GET' is not supported_. Ahí tenés una pista :)

Comment: Cuando cargas una página en el navegador usando la barra de direcciones **siempre** se está haciendo un `GET`

Comment: soy nuevo con spring y estoy aprendiendo, no entiendo que debo cambiar, tengo que usar get en vez de post?

Comment: Si quieres cargar una página, sí. usa la URL `http://localhost:8082/`

Answer (score 2):

En palabras simples, cuando el navegador accede a una pagina web realiza una llamada `GET` porque esta solicitando la pagina correspondiente a la url, al acceder a la url `localhost:8082/register` el navegador realiza una llamada de tipo `GET` pero al tener solo definido el método `POST` genera el error `Request method 'GET' is not supported`. Si accedes con el navegador por con la url `/register` tienes que definir un método anotado con `@GetMapping("/register")` ya que puedes tener los métodos `POST` y `GET` sobre la misma URL y dependiendo la acción se llamara a uno u otro.

Comment: Me ha ayudado mucho, ahora si lo entiendo, muchas gracias